# Angular 5 unit test route with guard

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a route that I need to prevent access from students. I'm trying to write a unit test for this, but it is not working.

My unit tests for the guard itself are working, however when I try to write a test that navigates to /class the canActivate method on the guard does not get called.

Here is the guard:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  const user = StoreActions.User.getCurrentUser(store.getState());

  if(!user) {
    this.router.navigate(['/pages/login']);
    return false;
  }

  if(user.username.match(/\d/) !== null) {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

And the test:

```
it(
  'should activate guard when a student tries to access /class',
  fakeAsync(
    inject([StudentGuard], (guard: StudentGuard) => {
      const spy = spyOn(guard, 'canActivate');
      store.dispatch(StoreActions.User.setCurrentUser(TestObjects.User.Student));
      router.navigate(['/class/1']);
      tick();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      discardPeriodicTasks();
    })
  )
);
```

Here is the specific route:

```
{
  path: '',
  children: {
    path: 'class',
    loadChildren: './components/class/class.module#ClassModule',
    canActivate: [StudentGuard]
  }
}
```

The `expect` statement fails in the test. However, if I actually impersonate a student and then navigate to /class in the browser the guard works as expected, but it does not activate in the test. How can I make it activate in the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. I found a few questions that were similar saying that karma was waiting for an observable to be resolved. I realized that `router.navigate` returns a promise and karma must be waiting for that to be resolved. I had to change my test to this:

```
it(
  'should activate guard when a student tries to access /class',
  fakeAsync(
    inject([StudentGuard], (guard: StudentGuard) => {
      const spy = spyOn(guard, 'canActivate');
      store.dispatch(StoreActions.User.setCurrentUser(TestObjects.User.Student));
      router.navigate(['/class/1']).then(() => { // added .then
          expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // put expect here, AFTER navigate is resolved
      });
      tick();
      discardPeriodicTasks();
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: what does your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` look like?  I tried the same thing and my guard still doesn't appear to be firing.  I am using a `CanDeactivate` guard, and including that in my mock routes.

Comment: @J-man Here is my entire file: https://gist.github.com/iHaruku/035a55737bd88f74d5ba6e5095802163